# How to add members to a Trello board?

Tags: trello

Members are trying to accept invitations to a board today and the emailed link is leaving them without any success. When we test drove the "add members" function on Monday the link directed one to sign-in or log-in and create an account. Has something changed?

Comment: What is happening when they click on the link?  Are they getting an error message?  What browser are they using?

Comment: @DanielLeCheminant I seem to be in the same situation. I created an account on Trello, requested an invitation to a board (out of band), got the invitation e-mail (sent 2011-09-24 03:15Z), clicked on the link (around 2011-09-24 11:30Z), and was redirected immediately to the usual board URL where I saw what seems to be exactly the same page as before (it's a public board). I'm still not a member of the board, and there doesn't seem to be any kind of “accept invitation” or “join board” button. I tried in both Chrome 14 and Firefox 5.

Comment: I'm also having an issue with people not being able to accept invitations. In my case, the two people I had invited, both got a message saying 'unauthorized' when they clicked on the link in the invitation. Both were also using Internet Explorer. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer were they using?  If it was less than version 9, they may have hit this bug: https://trello.com/card/board/if-you-try-to-accept-an-invite-with-an-unsupported-browser-you-get-an-unauthorized-message/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e822fd6491bb0c78ffc7892

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the issue that you're facing, but there is a bug in Trello that [prevents people from accepting invitations to public boards](https://trello.com/card/board/people-can-t-accept-invitations-to-public-boards/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e821c82e0573cce8f044202).

(The fix for that will go out with the next release of Trello)

Comment: I've now clicked my invite link again, and this time I saw an button to accept the invitation, which worked. I guess I'm confirming the fix works.